# mysql on virtualbox with datadir on shared folder

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, virtualbox

I've installed Ubuntu 10.10 on virtualbox machine. With apache/php/mysql ...
now I'm trying to move mysql datadir to folder shared by host os (win7)

so I've done following:
1) mounted shared folder: `sudo mount -t vboxsf -o uid=103,gid=110 mysql_h /mnt/db` uid,gid of mysql;
2) changed `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` so `datadir` will look like: `datadir = /mnt/db`;
3) restarted service.

while trying to connect to mysql, I get following error: `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

PS

```
user            = mysql
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port            = 3306
basedir         = /usr
datadir         = /mnt/db
tmpdir          = /tmp
```

**UPDATE**

I've changed the sharing mode from virtualbox to samba, and mount it using: `mount -t smbfs -o username=David,password=,uid=103,gid=110,rw //DAVID-PC/mysql /mnt/db`. It mounts okay, with mysql user/group as owners. But I still can't start mysql. 
error log:

```
110121 13:24:38 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
110121 13:24:38 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
110121 13:24:38  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

**UPDATE2**

```
grep mysql /etc/passwd
mysql:x:103:110:MySQL Server,,,:/nonexistent:/bin/false

ls -al /mnt/db/ib*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql 10485760 2011-01-21 13:45 /mnt/db/ibdata1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql  5242880 2011-01-21 13:45 /mnt/db/ib_logfile0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql  5242880 2011-01-21 13:45 /mnt/db/ib_logfile1
```

**UPDATE3a**

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql    4096 2011-01-21 23:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root     4096 2011-01-20 23:19 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql        4 2011-01-21 20:46 apache-server.pid
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql        0 2011-01-21 16:21 debian-5.1.flag
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql 10485760 2011-01-21 16:42 ibdata1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql  5242880 2011-01-21 23:12 ib_logfile0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql  5242880 2011-01-21 23:13 ib_logfile1
drwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql    20480 2011-01-21 16:21 mysql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql        6 2011-01-11 20:32 mysql_upgrade_info
```

**UPDATE4**

```
mysql@apache-server:/$ ls -la /mnt/db/mysql
total 970
drwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql  20480 2011-01-24 07:54 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql   4096 2011-01-24 07:54 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8820 2011-01-24 07:54 columns_priv.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 columns_priv.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   4096 2011-01-24 07:54 columns_priv.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   9582 2011-01-24 07:54 db.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 db.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   2048 2011-01-24 07:54 db.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql  10223 2011-01-24 07:54 event.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 event.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   2048 2011-01-24 07:54 event.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8665 2011-01-24 07:54 func.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 func.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   1024 2011-01-24 07:54 func.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql     35 2011-01-24 07:54 general_log.CSM
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 general_log.CSV
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8776 2011-01-24 07:54 general_log.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8700 2011-01-24 07:54 help_category.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql  22078 2011-01-24 07:54 help_category.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   3072 2011-01-24 07:54 help_category.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8612 2011-01-24 07:54 help_keyword.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql  89044 2011-01-24 07:54 help_keyword.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql  16384 2011-01-24 07:54 help_keyword.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8630 2011-01-24 07:54 help_relation.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8937 2011-01-24 07:54 help_relation.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql  17408 2011-01-24 07:54 help_relation.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8770 2011-01-24 07:54 help_topic.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql 425616 2011-01-24 07:54 help_topic.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql  20480 2011-01-24 07:54 help_topic.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   9510 2011-01-24 07:54 host.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 host.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   2048 2011-01-24 07:54 host.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8778 2011-01-24 07:54 ndb_binlog_index.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 ndb_binlog_index.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   1024 2011-01-24 07:54 ndb_binlog_index.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8586 2011-01-24 07:54 plugin.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 plugin.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   1024 2011-01-24 07:54 plugin.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   9996 2011-01-24 07:54 proc.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 proc.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   2048 2011-01-24 07:54 proc.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8875 2011-01-24 07:54 procs_priv.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 procs_priv.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   4096 2011-01-24 07:54 procs_priv.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8838 2011-01-24 07:54 servers.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 servers.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   1024 2011-01-24 07:54 servers.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql     35 2011-01-24 07:54 slow_log.CSM
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 slow_log.CSV
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8976 2011-01-24 07:54 slow_log.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8955 2011-01-24 07:54 tables_priv.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 tables_priv.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   4096 2011-01-24 07:54 tables_priv.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8636 2011-01-24 07:54 time_zone.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8624 2011-01-24 07:54 time_zone_leap_second.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 time_zone_leap_second.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   1024 2011-01-24 07:54 time_zone_leap_second.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 time_zone.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   1024 2011-01-24 07:54 time_zone.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8606 2011-01-24 07:54 time_zone_name.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 time_zone_name.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   1024 2011-01-24 07:54 time_zone_name.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8686 2011-01-24 07:54 time_zone_transition.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 time_zone_transition.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   1024 2011-01-24 07:54 time_zone_transition.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   8748 2011-01-24 07:54 time_zone_transition_type.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql      0 2011-01-24 07:54 time_zone_transition_type.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   1024 2011-01-24 07:54 time_zone_transition_type.MYI
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql  10466 2011-01-24 07:54 user.frm
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql    468 2011-01-24 07:54 user.MYD
-rwxr-xr-x 0 mysql mysql   2048 2011-01-24 07:54 user.MYI

mysql@apache-server:/$ sum /mnt/db/ibdata1
02939 10240

mysql@apache-server:/$ cat /mnt/db/small.txt
very small text file from windows

mysql@apache-server:/$ ls -la /mnt/db/small.txt
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql 33 2011-01-24 07:59 /mnt/db/small.txt

mysql@apache-server:/$ ls -la /mnt/db/mysql > /mnt/db/small
mysql@apache-server:/$ ls -la /mnt/db
total 20517
drwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql     4096 2011-01-24 08:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root  root      4096 2011-01-20 23:19 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql        0 2011-01-24 07:54 debian-5.1.flag
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql 10485760 2011-01-24 07:54 ibdata1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql  5242880 2011-01-24 07:54 ib_logfile0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql  5242880 2011-01-24 07:54 ib_logfile1
drwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql    20480 2011-01-24 07:54 mysql
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql        6 2011-01-24 07:54 mysql_upgrade_info
-rwxr-xr-x 1 mysql mysql     4562 2011-01-24 08:03 small
```

Comment: The error message suggests that mysqld failed to start. You need to check your logs to see why not.

Comment: checked the logs... I don't know what's the problem // tried to run upgrade

Comment: Can we see the outputs of `grep mysql /etc/passwd` and `ls -al /mnt/db/ibdata1` ?

Comment: ...just added :)

Comment: Mm.  As user mysql, could you do `touch /mnt/db/ibNOTAREALFILE`, `ls -al /mnt/db/`, `rm /mnt/db/ibNOTAREALFILE`, `sum /mnt/db/ibdata1`, and `touch /mnt/db/ibdata1`, and let us see the outputs?  Since you were kind enough to let me know all the files that matched /mnt/db/ib*, I'm pretty sure the ibNOTALREALFILE thing above won't harm anything permanently.  I suspect that mysql isn't able to open everything it wants to, and the above should help test that.

Comment: I'm a bit n00b in Linux, so this line "As user mysql" left me clueless. How can I log into terminal with user mysql?

Comment: You will need to become user mysql with (as root) `/bin/su - mysql`.  You may find that the mysql user doesn't have a real shell by default, in which case you'll need to change it with `usermod -s /bin/bash mysql` first (but check first with `finger mysql`, and change it back afterwards if you do change it).

Comment: thanks, added... learning a lot of new stuff as we go. How do I remove shell now?

Comment: `usermod -s /bin/false mysql`.  By the way, I really wanted an `ls -la /mnt/db`, as asked, not `ls -la /mnt/db/ib*`

Comment: done... btw, mysql user touched and removed files w/o asking for sudo

Comment: OK, time for a speculative answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end it was one another conf. file with datadir location. After fixing it - everything worked.

`/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld`

Comment: Ah yes! Apparmor was caused me troubles before when moving the datadir to new locations.

Answer (score 0):

The error can't be any more clear. It is a permissions issue. You are able to read/write the folder as your own user but what about the user mysql. Mysqld runs with permissions of user mysql therefore you need to make sure that user "mysql" can read and write to your data director.

Snippet of your log
**InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to

InnoDB: the directory.

InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1

InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.

InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.**

Comment: as I commented above, `mysql` is set to be the owner of that folder. Specifically this part: `uid=103,gid=110,rw`. may be I'm setting it wrong as `group` doesn't have write permissions

Answer (score 0):

David:

firstly, thanks for running all those tests above.  I'm glad that touch/rm as mysql worked without sudo, because that's what we were testing.  I agree with the others that the signs all point to a permissions problem, but I can see nearly no signs of one.

As a passing test, could I also get the output from 
`ls -la /mnt/db/mysql` ?

The only oddity in the data you've supplied is the output from `sum /mnt/db/ibdata1`, which used to be above but seems to have vanished, and if I recall correctly was something like

```
00000  320
```

That's odd because usually only a file full of zeros will give output like that.  It's possible for it to happen randomly, but there's only a one-in-a-hundred-thousand chance.  My gut feeling is that even a freshly-made mysql datafile shouldn't be totally empty.

Is it possible that somehow you're being allowed to list the directory, open files, etc., but the backend server is giving you only zeroes when the contents of a file are asked for?  Could you test this hypothesis by making a small textfile of known contents **on the Windows server side**, then trying

```
cat /mnt/db/SmallTextFile
```

on the Linux side, as user mysql?  A similar test where the file is both created and read on the Linux side (as user mysql in both cases) would be helpful, too.  I can't think of any other way to confirm that the file system will give back data that are put into it.

If that isn't it I'm rather out of ideas, sorry.  I'm glad you felt you were learning new stuff while we ran all these tests, though!

Comment: thanks a lot. See **Update4**. note r-x permissions for group, maybe it have something to do with _problem_. These files are copied from regular mysql datadir, and there they had another permissions, which I didn't change. `-rw-rw---- 1 mysql mysql   8820 2011-01-11 20:32 columns_priv.frm`. So I'm guessing that permissions are being set automatically by Samba.

Comment: Since the mysql database ought to run as the mysql user, the group permissions shouldn't matter.  One last lunatic fringe question: you *are* starting mysql as the root user, using the normal system startup scripts, aren't you?

Comment: yes. and I tried to stop service and restart it to several times. In the end it will be something stupid that we forgot to think about. :)

Comment: <grin> that's my fear, too.  when you say you started and stopped it, you mean something like `sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld start`, yes?

Comment: more like `sudo services mysql stop` or `start`

Comment: Crap, that should be fine, then.  I truly don't know why it's not working; I'm really sorry.

Comment: `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.mysqld` this file! there's two lines needed fixing